# file_get_contetnts and soap client don't work with long query

Tags: php, web-services, soap, file-get-contents

Sorry if this is duplicate,I would think it would be but couldn't find anything

I have an application using soap client web-service to connect to other server but recently I found out the requests with long text do not send to web-service.

I thought it related to some PHP configs and set `post_max_size` to `200M` and set `max_input_vars` to `10000` but the problem did not solve ...

today I found out `file_get_contents` don't work as well as soap client in my server and I am sure one of php configuration made this problem.

here is the code that dont work and when I run this just wait for a while and display nothing ( white page)

> $url="http://somedomain.com/webservice.php?Username=user&Password=pass&Det=13218%5E04134414401%5E7015373%5E3%5E51%5E14%252F2141-9305-310209-424926%25D8%25A2%25D9%2585%25D9%2588%25D8%25B2%25D8%25B4%2B%25D9%2583%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D8%25AF%25D9%258A%2BHTML%2B5.0%2B%2526%2BCSS%2B3.0%2B%25D9%2587%25D9%2585%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D9%2587%2B%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%2BResponsive%2BWeb%2BDesign%25D9%2585%25D8%25B1%25D8%25AC%25D8%25B9%2B%25D8%25A2%25D9%2585%25D9%2588%25D8%25B2%25D8%25B4%25D9%258A%2B%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D9%2586%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585%25D9%2587%25E2%2580%258C%25D9%2586%25D9%2588%25D9%258A%25D8%25B3%25D9%258A%2BASP.NET%2B4.5%2B%25D8%25AF%25D8%25B1%2BC%2523%2B%2528%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B2%2B%25D9%2585%25D8%25A8%25D8%25AA%25D8%25AF%25D9%258A%2B%25D8%25AA%25D8%25A7%2B%25D9%25BE%25D9%258A%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B1%25D9%2581%25D8%25AA%25D9%2587%2529%25D9%2585%25D8%25B1%25D8%25AC%25D8%25B9%2B%25D9%2583%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585%25D9%2584%2BASP.Net%2BMVC%2B4%5E2825%5E819700%5E1%5E0%5E%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585%25DB%258C%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B6%25D8%25A7%2B%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B3%25D8%25AF%25D9%25BE%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%5E%25D8%25AA%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25DB%258C%25D8%25B2%2B-%2B%25DA%2586%25D9%2587%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D9%2587%2B%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2587%2B%25D9%2585%25D8%25AC%25D8%25AA%25D9%2585%25D8%25B9%2B%25D8%25AA%25D8%25AC%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B1%25DB%258C%2B%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2587%2B%25D8%25B7%25D8%25A8%25D9%2582%25D9%2587%2B%25D8%25A7%25D9%2588%25D9%2584%2B%25D9%2588%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AD%25D8%25AF%2B5%5E5178735466%5Einfo%2540pendarepars.com%5E154000%5E12320&Ordertip=1";
>
> echo file_get_contents($url);

Comment: This is 16xx characters long, the length of this URL should not be an issue. The issue is most likely due to a break in the URL encoding schema somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this issue by sending the request as a **post** not **Get**

Answer (score 0):

You should check what the server is responding with using cUrl. This snippet should help you on your way.

```
// Prep cUrl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);

// Output info
echo "<pre>";
if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo "Error: ".curl_error($ch)."\n";
}
else
{
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo htmlentities($return);
}
```

Look for http_code, if it's 414 then the server can't handle the length of the URI.